# Subclassing DataTable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm using Entity Framework and a stored proc that takes a table valued parameter (TVP). To do this, I need to create a `DataTable` and populate it like so:

```
var i = new DataTable();
i.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(byte));
i.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
i.Rows.Add(0, 0);
i.Rows.Add(2, 31);
i.Rows.Add(4, 3121);
i.Rows.Add(4, 3111);
```

And then I can pass it as a parameter to a call to `SqlQuery`

```
var result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<MyResult>("select * from myStoredProc(@i)",
    new SqlParameter("@i",i) { TypeName = "MyTVP" });
```

Now to simplify this, especially recreating the columns every time, I though I could subclass `DataTable`, something like this:

```
public class MyTVP : DataTable
{
    public MyTVP()
        : base()
    {
        Columns.Add("Type", typeof(byte));
        Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
    }
}
```

So now my code to create and populate the table is this:

```
var i = new MyTVP();
i.Rows.Add(0, 0);
i.Rows.Add(2, 31);
i.Rows.Add(4, 3121);
i.Rows.Add(4, 3111);
```

But if I try to pass this as a parameter to the stored proc I get an `ArgumentException`:

```
No mapping exists from object type MyTVP to a known managed provider native type.
```

Is there a way to subclass `DataTable` such that you can pass it to the stored proc?

I worked around this problem by having `MyTVP` wrap a `DataTable` instead and then have a property that exposes the `DataTable`, but it's a little messy.

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, Object value, Boolean inferLen, Boolean streamAllowed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.get_DbType()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.LogParameter[TResult](DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext, DbParameter parameter)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.LogCommand[TResult](DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.Executing[TResult](DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter.ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__d(IDbCommandInterceptor i, DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__64()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__63()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass14`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__13()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\matt.burland\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 72
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: You could reverse the problem: make a static method that returns a `DataTable`, or a fluent interface with something like: MyTVPBuilder.Create().Add(0,0).Add(2,31).ToDataTable()

Comment: Can you give me the full stacktrace, so I can watch where the error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the parameter to:

```
new SqlParameter("@i", i) { TypeName = "MyTVP", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured }
```

Comment: Ha. That seems to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be instead of creating a new type create a DataTable factory that create the datatables with the right columns on it.